# How to get browser name in cakephp 3 request?

Tags: php, cakephp-3.0

I need to get requesting browsers name in my web app.( for analytics )

In core php when I use `$visitor_user_agent=$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']`it returns `Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.130 Safari/537.36` string when using with chrome.And then `preg_match('/Chrome/i', $visitor_user_agent)` can be used to know if its chrome or not.I am not sure if that was efficient way to find browser name or not.

I also found [get_browser](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php) link but it is not giving browser name.

Is there a way in cakephp3 or core php to get browser name ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look into [documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/request-response.html#request) of `Request` object.

You can get `HTTP_USER_AGENT` using `env()` method:

```
$this->request->env('HTTP_USER_AGENT');
```

You can also prepare custom detector:

```
$this->request->addDetector(
    'chrome',
    ['env' => 'HTTP_USER_AGENT', 'pattern' => '/Chrome/i']
);
```

And then in controller just use `is()` method as follows:

```
if($this->request->is('chrome')) {
    // do stuff for chrome
}
```

Comment: So basically the logic is same as I explained above in core php,but it is cakephp3  way of implementation.

Comment: `env()` is deprecated. Use `getEnv()` instead.

Answer (score 3):

This would return the user agent used for the request:

```
$this->request->header('User-Agent');
```

http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/request-response.html